# Calculate hidden fields with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that i'm trying to calculate some monetary value based on 2 dropdowns then show the total amount only the total in a textbox called `GrandTotal` which is read only.

Page loads and gets pricing data from DB into hidden fields.

> InitialPrice = 660 (Mandatory)
>
> EQup1Price =  550
>
> EQup2Price =  440

2 Drop downs (EQup1, EQup2) Values 1-5.

Buy greater than 1 and get one free for EQup1 and EQup2.

The calculation is whats doing my head in.

```
 <p>InitialPrice -: <strong>$660.00</strong></p>
 <form name="Edit" method="post" action="mypageprocess">
<p><label for="EQup1">How many Branches?</label><br /><select name="EQup1" onblur="calc(this.form)" id="EQup1"/>    
        <option value="0">Please select</option> 
        <option value="1" >One</option>
        <option value="2" >Two</option>
        <option value="3" >Three</option>
        <option value="4" >Four</option>
        <option value="5" >Five</option>
        </select> &nbsp;&nbsp; x <strong>$550.00</strong>
</p> 


<p><label for="EQup2">How many Satellits?</label><br /><select name="EQup2" onblur="calc(this.form)" id="EQup2"/>    
        <option value="0">Please select</option> 
        <option value="1" >One</option>
        <option value="2" >Two</option>
        <option value="3" >Three</option>
        <option value="4" >Four</option>
        <option value="5" >Five</option>
        </select> &nbsp;&nbsp; x <strong>$440.00 </strong>
</p> 


<input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" name="GrandTotal" size="10" readonly="readonly"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="InitialPrice" value="660" />
        <input type="hidden" name="EQup1Price" value="550" />
        <input type="hidden" name="EQup2Price" value="440" />
     </form>

        <script>
          function calc(theForm) {
          // console.log("calc(theForm)");


        var myEquip1 = document.Edit.EQup1.value;
        var myEquip2 = document.Edit.EQup2.value;
        Var myFixedPrice = document.Edit.InitialPrice.value;

Var myEquip1Price = document.Edit.EQup1Price.value;
Var myEquip2Price = document.Edit.EQup2Price.value;

    if  (myEquip1 > 1)
{
    var myEquip1Total = (myEquip1*myEquip1Price) - (myEquip1Price)

}
else
 {
    var myEquip1Total = (myEquip1*myEquip1Price) - (myEquip1Price)

}

    if  (myEquip2 > 1)
{
    var myEquip2Total = (myEquip2*myEquip2Price) - (myEquip2Price)

}
else
 {
    var myEquip2Total = (myEquip2*myEquip2Price) - (myEquip2Price)

}
    
    theForm.GrandTotal.value = (myEquip2Total + myEquip1Total + myFixedPrice)
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Would be easier to help you if you show your code..

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Your Question was not so clear? what you are trying to ask? You can get the hidden field value by $("#EQup1").val().

Comment: I've posted the html and the code any guidance will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

to calculate hidden fields in jquery

`$(":hidden").length`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#GrandTotal").val(Number($("#EQup1").val()) + Number($("#EQup1").val()));
```